# How to add double back-slashes insead of a single back-slashes using JFileChooser

Tags: java, eclipse, path, jfilechooser, backslash

I am creating a program to search for a directory path. I have used JFileChooser to do this which is great. This is the code for it.

```
JButton btnPathBrowser = new JButton("Select Database");
        btnPathBrowser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                int response = fc.showOpenDialog(Create.this);
                if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION); {
                    txtPath.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().toString());
                    //fileName = fc.getSelectedFile().toString();

                }


            }
        });
```

Now when I run this I get the path written in this way.
[GUI showing the Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wElRw.png)

So you can see that the path is separated with a single back-slash e.g.C:\User\Folder\Database but I want it to spate the path with two back-slashes like this. C:\Users\Database. I tried this but got errors:

```
txtPath.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().toString().replace("\", "\\"));
```

I want to use it like this:

```
String  sourceFileName              = new String(txtPath.getSelectedText());
```

I am quite new to this so any pointers in the right direction with my code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to replace anything. You only need to escape the slashes in String literals, such as

```
String myPath = "C:\\foo\\bar";
```

Even then, you could just use the platform independent version

```
String myPath = "C:/foo/bar";
```

If you really needed to replace slashes with double slashes, you'd have to escape them (as the parameters are String literals), so you'd end up with

```
String foo = bar.replace("\\", "\\\\"); // Convert one slash to two slashes
```

Additionally if you were to use `replaceAll` method which takes regular expressions as parameters, you'll need double escaping. Once for the String literal and once for the regex engine:

```
String foo = bar.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\"); // Convert one slash to two slashes
```

But to reiterate, in your case you **don't need** double slashes.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me a lot!